# Counting repeated 5-mers gene from 100 DNA sequence samples

Tags: r, dna-sequence

I am beginner in R and trying to solve this but have been struggling for few days already. Please help a newbie out.

I extracted 100 samples each of length 1000 from a 100,000 DNA sequence. Then, I want to count "AATAA" appeared how many times in the each of the sample.

```
dog_100
#  [1] "GGGTCCTTGAAAGAAGCACAGGGTGGGGGTGGGGGTGGGGGTGGGGGAAGGCAGAGAGGAGGAAACAGGTTTTTGTCCTCAGGGCGTTGCCAGTCTGAAGGAGGTGATGGGATAATTATTTATGAGAGTTCAGGAATGCCAGGCATGGATTAAATGCAAACTAATGGAAATGACACAGAACAATACATTACAC......................................"
#[2] "CCAGGCCAGAACTGAGGCCCTCAGGGCCCCCCAGAATTCCTCATTTGCAGGATAAAAATATACTCAGCTCTTCAATCTTGGTTCTTGCTACTGCACCATGTGCTTCCTGGACTCTGGGAGGCCAGGGGTTAAGTGGGAGTGTTTGAATAAGGGAAAGGATGAGCCCTTTCCCCACACTTTGCCCCAAATAAC......................................"
#[3]
#........
# [4]
#........
# [100]
#........
```

I wrote a function to identify and count the "AATAA".

```
R

library(stringr)

cal_AATAA <- function(DNA){
  sam_pro <- numeric(length(DNA))
  k <- 5
  sam_code <- "AATAA"
  for(i in 1:(length(DNA))){
    Num <- str_length(DNA[i])
    for(j in 1:(Num - k +1)){
      if ((str_sub(DNA[i], j, j+k-1)) == sam_code){
        sam_pro[i] <- sam_pro[i] + 1
      }
      else {
        sam_pro[i] <- sam_pro[i]
      }
    }
    return (sam_pro)
  }
}

sample_100 <- cal_AATAA(dog_100)
```

What I got after running the function is

```
> sample_100
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [46] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [91] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Tried to debug my code but don't know where went wrong. Appreciate any tips or guidance.

Answer (score 2):

R has a built in function called `gregexpr` which can be used for counting patterns in a string. It outputs a `list`, so we have to use `sapply` to loop through the elements of the output. For each element, we count the number of values that are greater than zero because a value of `-1` indicates that any match was not found. Look at the output of `gregexpr("ap", c("appleap", "orange"))` as an example.

```
dna = c("AGTACGTGCATAGC", "GTAGCTAGCTAGCAT")
sam = "AGC"
sapply(gregexpr(sam, dna), function(x) sum(x > 0))
#[1] 1 3
```